# In what kind of situations should I not care about the Maintainability Index in Visual Studio's Code Metrics?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-metrics, maintainability

I just today stumbled upon the Code Metrics thing, after having used Visual Studio practically every day for... practically my whole life. I think it's been there since around VS2008, but I haven't cared to play with it.

Most of my projects in my solution have fairly high Maintainability Indices -- 85, 83, 86, and 76 and 59 on my "scrap" projects. I do remember putting very little effort into making those scrap projects presentable, so I agree with the index.

But I can't imagine it being a perfect measure. In what situations should I rightfully disagree with an index?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936814/visual-studio-code-metrics-and-the-maintainability-index-of-switch-case

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[A Practical Model for Measuring Maintainability](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.120.4996&rep=rep1&type=pdf)" talks about the problems with the maintainability index.  One of the main drawbacks is that it is a composite index of several other metrics, so it's hard to say *why* the score is bad.